# Let $V$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$...

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space of $\mathbb{C}$
$V=\{(x,y) : x,y \in \mathbb{R} \}$ show that dimV = 4.
And teacher gave a hint:  Show that $B=\{(1,0),(i,0)(0,1)(0,i)\}$ spans(generates).

So i should begin like this? To show that $B$ spans $\exists a ,b,c,d$ such that $a(1,0)+b(i,o)+c(0,1)+d(0,i)+..$ ? and if yes im not sure what to do next

Comment: Do you mean $V=\{(x,y) : x,y \in \mathbb{C} \}$?

Comment: As @Arthur said and I shall add, is $V$ a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: I think you you look at $V$ (like in Arthur's comment) as a $\mathbb{R}$ vectorspace and you want to show $\dim_{\mathbb{R}}V=4$

Comment: No in $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{C}$

Answer (score 0):

Your vector space $V$ is over $\mathbb{R}$ and the vectors of $V$ are ordered pairs of complex numbers, otherwise it isn't coherent with the fact that $dim (V)=4$ and with the fact that your base $B$ has complex ordered pairs.

That said, you must prove that any vector of $V$ can be written as a linear combination of the vectors of $B$, since a vector of $V$ is of the form $(a+bi,c+di)$ you just need to note that :
$$(a+bi,c+di)=(a,c)+(bi,di)=((a,0)+(0,c))+((bi,0)+(0,di))=(a(1,0)+c(0,1))+(b(i,0)+d(0,i))=a(1,0)+b(i,0)+c(0,1)+d(0,i)$$
Now you must prove that $B$ is a linearly indepentent set, so if you assume: $$(0,0)=a(1,0)+b(i,0)+c(0,1)+d(0,i)$$ then you have $$(0,0)=(a+bi,c+di)$$ Now, two ordered pairs are equal if and only if they have the same first component and the same second component, so you have: $$a+bi=0$$ $$c+di=0$$ these are equalities of complex numbers and they equal zero, which means that both the real and the imaginary part must equal zero, so it must be the case that $a=b=c=d=0$

Recall that when you sum two (or as many as you want) pairs of complex numbers you must sum the first component of the first pair with the first component of the second oair and the same for the second components and the result is another ordered pair of complex numbers. And when you multiply a pair of complex numbers by a scalar you have to multiply both components by that scalar.

Hope it is clearer now, if you have more doubt don't hesitate to ask them.

Comment: so we write $a+bi+c+di=a+c+i(b+d)$ then $a+c+i(b+d)=a+bi$ and $a+c+i(b+d)=c+di$ ?

Comment: and in the second part $a+bi+c+di=o \rightarrow a+c+i(d+b)=0$ So $a+c=0$ and $d+b=0$ ?

Comment: No, you have to consider the coordinates of the pair by separate, you don't have to sum them, I will edit the anwser to clarify it